How would you respond to this claim by Christians?
My friend is an evangelical pastor and he argues that Christ could be the messiah through the female linage of Mary, I am currently struggling to respond to this and wondered how you would respond? I've included a transcript of what he said below:

The was from the direct linage of David. You say “The biological father
decides which tribe the son belongs to.”. This isn’t so in Jewish
tradition. Although it’s difficult to show why the Rabbis use the
maternal line, nevertheless they do. So Mary's genealogy (Luke 3) is
the determining factor.
You need to remember that the eligibility of Jesus for being entitled
to the throne is a question for the Jews to settle. Not ‘us
westerners’. Let’s look at some criteria they expect. Remember that
due to the historical split, there are two distinct branches for this
nation. Judah, (and Benjamin), and Israel (Northern 10 tribes).
The requirements for sitting on the throne for Judah was Davidic
descendancy. No one was allowed to sit on David's throne unless he was
a member of the house of David. Now the ‘key point’ here is house of
David. Not bloodline.
This is crucial - because there was a curse put onto Davids bloodline.
From Jeconiah. (Jeremiah 22 24-30). So Jesus couldn’t be a ‘blood’
descendant of David! That’s why Jesus couldn’t have a ‘blood’
connection to Joseph. But nevertheless had a connection to David
through Joseph, as Joseph was ‘legally’ [in Jewish/Mosaic law] Jesus’s
father.
So Jesus had a ‘legally accepted’ connection to the house of David
through both Joseph, and Mary - and also was not ‘under’ the curse God
pronounced on Jeconiah.
Now for the Northern house of Israel - to be King here, came by
prophetic sanction or divine appointment. So ‘technically’ Jesus had
to be eligible under two sets of requirements.
So, why or how could Jesus claim the throne of David? He was a member
of the house of David apart from Jeconiah. And, He alone received
divine appointment to that throne: (“The Lord God will give him the
throne of his father David
I


Why did you create a new account to ask basically the same question that you've asked through your previous account and have already been informed that it's a duplicate?

I wouldn’t dignify such claims by bothering to respond to them.

It's the second coming

@ClintEastwood hah! good one.

You've been asked to cease and desist. Please.

You can't win of you argue this point. If you focus on minutiae, the pastor will call you a minutiae oriented Pharisee who misses the big picture.
He could say that Jesus inherits his kingship from his father, God. (Or that. David dies, God inherits him, passes to his son). Remember, protestants don't have a stodgy pope holding their theology in check.
Jesus's non Messiahship is based on his failure to actually rule, ingather exiles, revive all of the dead (not just a few people) etc. its the big things that matter.

God's word in the Hebrew Bible indicates that Tribal affiliation is patrilinear.
Numbers 1:2
Take the sum of all the congregation of the children of Israel, by families following their fathers' houses.
Ibid. 1:18
and they assembled all the congregation on the first day of the second month, and they declared their pedigrees according to their families according to their fathers' houses.
Ezra 2:59
but they could not tell their fathers' houses and their children, if they were from Israel.

Given the great lengths the gospel writers went to spell out Jesus' "exact" genealogy from David, they were evidently well aware that according to Biblical Law tribal affiliation goes exclusively via the father, and they intended to establish that.
In both putative genealogies of Jesus; in Matthew 1:6, and the other in Luke 3:31, the ancestry of David is mentioned ... for Jesus (not Mary).
Consider also Luke 1:27, which plainly asserts that it is Joseph who was from the House of David, not Mary.
Moreover, in Luke 2:4, the author writes that the reason it was necessary for Joseph and Mary to return to Bethlehem, was because it was Joseph, not Mary, who was from the House of David.
According to the Hebrew Bible, the Messiah will be a patrilineal descendant of King David, something that Jesus could never be; since according to the legend of the virgin birth, he did not have a biological father.
There is no basis in Jewish law for a father passing on his tribal line by adoption. So Joseph adopting baby Jesus, who allegedly had no Jewish tribal lineage, could not make Jesus part of Joseph's tribe.
